# How to get product details using asin no in amazon using rest api?

Tags: php, curl, amazon-s3, amazon-product-api

I am trying to get amazon product details using rest api(curl).

Iam tring to get amazon product details using curl and its asin no but when iam dumping the response its showing null.
iam using $url="https://asin2ean.p.mashape.com/com/".$asin in order to get details but might be the url that iam using is not working or any other issues.
This url is provided by my senior so iam hestiate a bit in arguiing with him so kindly suggest me where iam going wrong.

MY CODE:

```
   $url= 'https://asin2ean.p.mashape.com/com/'.$asin;
   $ch=curl_init();
       $timeout = 4;
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Basic ZXp6eW9mZmVyc0BnbWFpbC5jb206QmFoYW1hczE3','X-Mashape-Key: 0ditKgdkQTmsh7eNQPBRZq7nm6lJp1ws5p3jsnpx1okLkSFnKx','Accept: application/json'));
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
       //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
       $response = curl_exec($ch);
       curl_close($ch);
       //$arrproduct= json_decode($presponse ,true);
       $arrproduct = json_decode($presponse ,true);
       //$arr=["hello","hi"];
       //var_dump($arr);
       echo "<br>";
       var_dump($response );
       $product_name = $arrproduct['Title'];
       $category_name = $arrproduct['Category'];
```

Comment: kindly let me know whether iam using correct url for fetching amazon product details or not? any suggestion would be appreciable...

Comment: can anyone suggest?